# Mongoose conditional required field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

The schema should be defined, so that an attribute `b` is required iff the attribute `a` is set to false.

```
const { Schema, model } = require("mongoose");

const schema = new Schema({
  a: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  b: {
    type: Number,
    required: function () {
      return !this.a;
    }
  }
});

const Model = model("bla", schema);

Model.validate({a: true});
```

But if I define the schema as above, the validate call in the last line will throw an error that `b` is required, even if `a` is set to `false`:

```
ValidationError: Validation failed: b: Path `b` is required.
```

The problem thems to be, that this is not referring to the schema, but to the function and there is no value `a` defined, so the function will only evaluate to `true` and b is always required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `Model.validate()`, you need to pass the context as the third parameters to make it work correctly. Something like `Model.validate({a: true}, ['b'], {a: true})` as mentioned in this [issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/10132). Or you can use `Document.prototype.validate()` instead:

```
let model = new Model({a: true}); 
model.validate();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have removed the exclamation mark, so it fits the description, but the problem is still the same.

Comment: Which mongoose version are you using?

Comment: The mongoose version is 5.12.13.

Comment: I've tested this and it work as expected. Can you show the code used to create the document?

Comment: Thank you for testing it by yourself. By changing the exclamation mark, I changed the code snippet inconsistently. I have adjusted the snippet now, accordingly.

Comment: With `Model.validate()`, you need to pass the context as the third parameters to make it work correctly. Unfortunately, I can't find any example of using context with `Model.validate()`. Just guess it's something like `Model.validate({a: true}, ['b'], {a: true});`

Comment: I suggest using `Document.prototype.validate()` instead. For example: `let model = new Model({a: true}); model.validate();`

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/10132

Comment: Thank you, especially the linked issue was helpful. Can you edit your answer, so I can accept the answer?